# How Can My Script Read Column Headers in a For Loop And Have User Identify Which Column Header to Use?

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python script that works well -- it creates QR codes from a CSV and stores them while adding the img file path to the end of the CSV.

There's just two updates I want to make that I can't crack:

1. Currently I have this line `id, first, last = row` in the reader loop which identifies the column headers from the csv. But it only works if there are three columns so they match. Is there any way to change this so it would work whether there are three columns or 20? (Should keep in mind that the script also writes two additional columns at the end of the columns.)
2. Also the QR codes are currently generated by whatever the first column in the CSV is because it's defined as having created them via the `id` column. Is there any way to have the user identify which column the QR codes should be based on as opposed to always assuming it's the first column?

Here's an example of the data that works (but wouldn't work if there were more columns):

```
ID    First    Last
144   Jerry    Seinfeld
491   George   Costanza
104   Elaine   Benes
99    Cosmo    Kramer
```

And here's the current script that works except these two tweaks (thanks to some others on StackOverflow to get me this far!):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import qrcode
import os
import shutil
import time
import inquirer

# Identify Timestamp
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

local = 'NBC'

# Load csv
filename = "stackoverflowtest.csv"

# Path to new local folder
localfolder = local
localimagefolder = os.path.join(localfolder, 'image')
localfilefolder = os.path.join(localfolder, 'files')

# Check/create folders based on local
if not os.path.exists(localfolder):
    os.makedirs(localfolder)
if not os.path.exists(localimagefolder):
    os.makedirs(localimagefolder)
if not os.path.exists(localfilefolder):
    os.makedirs(localfilefolder)

# Copy uploaded file to their local's file folder
target = os.path.join(localfilefolder, local+'-'+timestr+'.csv') # Target filename

# Read csv and generate QR code for local+first column of csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile, open(target, 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row.

    for row in reader:
        id, first, last = row  # This is where I would like `id, first, last` to actually be just whatever the columns are in the CSV

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )

        qr.add_data(local+"-"+id) # This is where it would be great to not assume that the first column is always going to be their ID
        qr.make()

        img = qr.make_image()
        imagepath = os.path.join(localimagefolder, local+"-"+id+".png")
        img.save(imagepath) # Save image.
        print "saving img:", imagepath

        writer.writerow(row + [local+'-'+id, imagepath])
```

For #1, I attempted to substitute `id, first, last =  row` with something like this but it didn't work:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = reader.next()
```

And for #2, I attempted to do a `raw_input` request to ask the user what their column name is called, but I don't know if that's the best route -- and don't think it would work anyway until #1 is fixed.

Thank you!

Comment: Re #1: Will the first three columns always be the same, with the same names?

Comment: @BillBell      Hi! If they were going to be the same with the same names then the current script would work fine. My ideal scenario is that even if someone uploads a CSV with 20 columns, the script will update and accept the 20 -- with still writing the two additional columns as 21 and 22.

Comment: Not the point I'm trying to raise! Will 'ID' always be column one, and will it always be called 'ID'? (I notice that it's the only column used in the script.)

Comment: @BillBell      That's the other thing I'm trying to solve. Right now, it only works if the ID column is is column one -- but I would like to figure out a way to make it work that it would function fine regardless of which column and what it was called, whether that be from user input or something else. Would just be nice to not have it be so restrictive. Ideal world someone uploads their csv and even if it has 20 columns and the ID is the seventh, the script would figure out a way to still use the ID column to make the QR codes.

Comment: If I were writing it I would use DictReader from the csv module to get the available column names, and I would write a simple dialog box using tkinter to ask the user to choose one of those names. Then I would let the csv loop with the information about which of the columns to treat as the id. Come to think of it, I'd put the filename selection together with with  column name selection in the same dialog. As soon as the user selects a filename csv could be opening the file and populating the dropdown for column selection.

Comment: @BillBell      Thank you! I actually already use tkinter in the other version of this script to have the user select the csv so maybe that won't be all that difficult. If you have an answer using this method, I'd very much appreciate it! Otherwise I'll try to give it another shot with the outline.

Comment: I don't have a ready-made answer. If you give it a shot and get stuck please feel free put another question, then leave another comment here for me and I'll gladly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you use format on your strings to make your image name more readable:

e.g:

```
image_name = "{local_name}-{id}.png".format(local_name=local, id=id)
```

Open your file with `'r'` instead of `'rb'`.

```
# such that
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = reader.next()

    # I'd probably also change i to headers
    headers = reader.next()
```